# source command is not working with variables or quoted strings

Tags: bash, scripting

I am having a problem with this.

If I do...

```
source /Users/cristian/Proyectos/MikroTik\ Updater/sources/testfile
```

It does work

If I do...

```
source "/Users/cristian/Proyectos/MikroTik\ Updater/sources/testfile"
```

It doesn’t

The problem is that I’m using a variable which contains a path got some steps before

So this...

```
mypath="/Users/cristian/Proyectos/MikroTik\ Updater/sources/testfile"
source $mypath
```

Doesn’t work neither

I found a workaround doin...

```
eval "source $mypath"
```

But of course it is a big security hole because file name comes from an argument

What can I do?

**EDIT:**

As you can see in the code I echo the filename and then try to source it

```
updaterpath="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P | sed  's/ /\\ /g' )"
sourcefile="$updaterpath/sources/$1"

echo $sourcefile
source $sourcefile
```

In the output I get the correct path echoed and the error from `source` saying it doesn't exists! The funny thing is that whether I `cat` that file, I can see the content, so the file path is correct!

```
/Users/cristian/Proyectos/MikroTik\ Updater/sources/testfile
/Users/cristian/Proyectos/MikroTik Updater/updater.sh: line 7: /Users/cristian/Proyectos/MikroTik\: No such file or directory
```

Comment: ShellCheck points out that you're using unicode slanted quotes `“` instead of ascii quotes `"`

Comment: I don't know why those quotes are there, I typed the correct ones but I think the StackOverflow iOS app changed them from " to “. I am gonna edit the post in the computer

Comment: iOS and macOS has a tendency to do this. They call it "smart quotes". You don't post any error messages, but from your description it sounds like these quotes ended up in your script as well.

Comment: What is the actual path? Absent characters that require quoting, there is literally no difference bretween `source /path/to/file` and `source "/path/to/file"`; the quotes are removed by the shell before `source` is executed.

Comment: No, I am a programmer, I have miles of lines written down, I know what I am doing in that aspect, I'm just having problems with something I am not accustomed to which is bash, nothing else. So please, stop talking about quotes because I use iOS and macOS from 10 years now and know what they do! It was my mistake not to double check before posting, that's all! Could you help me with my issue? I am going to edit again to add the error !

Comment: If you are using a variable, the correct usage is `source "$mypath"` to guard agains word-splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: I have edited the post to add some code and error message

Comment: Oh -- you have **literal** backslashes in your path. Yeah, that explains the problem.

Comment: Basically, you should never, **ever** try to use `sed` to escape a path.

Comment: BTW, see [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) re: why `$0` is unreliable for finding your script location.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok, I ended using that after trying some stuff and the bug stayed there! Now I have removed `sed` and did  `source "$sourcefile"` and everything is working! :)

Answer (score 5):

Your original question didn't include the faulty code:

```
### THIS IS BROKEN: the backslashes added by sed are literal, not syntactic
path=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd -P | sed 's/ /\\ /g')
source $path/sources/$1
```

The `sed` is the source of your problem. Just get rid of it:

```
### THIS IS CORRECT: The syntactic quotes mean no backslashes are needed.
# ...also handles the case when the cd fails more gracefully.
path=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P) || exit
source "$path/sources/$1"
```

...or, even better:

```
source "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/sources/$1"
```

---

**Backslashes are only meaningful when parsed as syntax. Results of string expansion do not go through these parsing steps.** This is the same reason literal quotes can't be used to build a command in a string, as discussed in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: I ended up using `sed` after trying some stuff and the bug stayed there! Now I have removed `sed` and did  `source "$sourcefile"` which worked! Sometimes, after some hours of work, what one just needs is a pair of additional eyes! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The code stayed this way if someone needs to see it

```
updaterpath="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
sourcefile="$updaterpath/sources/$1"

echo $sourcefile
source "$sourcefile"
```

Comment: As an aside, it'd be advisable to quote the argument to `echo`, as in `echo "$sourcefile"`. Otherwise, there are some changes between the actual command and the command-as-displayed that could be lost -- for instance, your filename has spaces; if it had two spaces in a row, the unquoted expansion would only show one. If the name contained a whitespace-surrounded `*`, the unquoted version would replace that with a list of files in the current directory. Etc.

Comment: (to explain why those effects happen -- when the expansion isn't quoted, the name is broken up into individual words, and then each of those words is evaluated as a glob expression, before passing the results as an array of C strings to `echo`, which puts a single space between each argument, not having any way to know how many spaces were there originally).